# get_title without filter(the_title)

Tags: filters, get-the-title

I'm using a function to filter the_title, adding a string onto the end, but would also like to return the original title, unfiltered on the same page. Is there a way to get the title without it being filtered?

Comment: Did you try `remove_filter()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this, but I would argue that the preferred way is, in general, fetching the `post_title` attribute from the post object. This does not depend on removing all filters for a certain function and adding them back later — the latter requires you to directly access the global `$wp_filter`.

[`get_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) retrieves the post object for a post ID, and the post object, on construction, populates all post fields with the fields from the database, without applying any filtering.

Thus, your code would simply be

```
$title = get_post( $post_id )->post_title;
```

If the post with ID `$post_id` is not guaranteed to exist, be sure to check whether the returned value from `get_post` is a post object.

NB another approach is to use `get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id )`, which by default only has the filter `'post_title'` applied to it (and not the `the_title` filter). However, as @PatJ kindly pointed out, using the optional `$context` parameter, you can get the raw value using the context `"raw"`:

```
get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id, 'raw' );
```

Comment: It would be better to use `get_post_field( 'post_title' );` for that, because it includes checks. PS Just noticed you updated ;-)

Comment: Hehe, updated my answer at exactly the same time. `get_post_field` applies the `post_title` filter, so you're not getting the raw data. `get_post` doesn't really run the risk of not returning an object with the post title property, but I understand your concern; I'd rather do the `isset` check myself then.

Comment: [`get_post_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/) has an optional `context` parameter, which will accept `'raw'` as a context. So to get the unfiltered `post_title`, you can use `get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id, 'raw' )`.

Comment: Good point @PatJ, I've updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function, put this in `functions.php`:

```
function get_title_no_filters($post = 0){

    $post = get_post( $post );

    echo isset( $post->post_title ) ? $post->post_title : '';
}
```

use it like this, just like the `get_the_title` WordPress offers:

```
get_title_no_filters();//inside a loop no need to send ID or post object
```

if you are not using it in a loop you can send an ID or a Post Object. This is the `raw` title no filters.